# sql i need to parse text without creating a function

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing, sql-server-2012

I do not have the access needed to create a function; but I need to be able to parse the following text.

```
ID           value
684286211   96756263;97051390
683855568   96825924;96862563;96862652;96862684;96862692
```

needing:

```
ID               value
684286211       96756263 
684286211       97051390
683855568       96825924
683855568       96862563
683855568       96862652
683855568       96862684
683855568       96862692
```

I have tried using the Parsename statement but it only works on 4 or less sections; I need to allow up to nine values.

using sql 2012

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What language are you using?  How is your sql table set up?  You need to give us more info.

Comment: can the delimiter be `space` or `semi-colon` or any other character ? What is the database?

Comment: I need to be able to parse in sql;it is a semicolon, however I can replace it with whateveris needed.

Comment: Can u specify the lang

Comment: TSQL-2012; I need a select query to parse this with

Comment: You shouldn't store delimited values in a single column. It would be better if you fixed your data model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE for this purpose:

```
with CTE as (
      select id, value,
             left(value, charindex(';', value)) as val,
             substring(value, charindex(';', value) + 1, len(value))+';' as restval
     from t
     where value like '%;%'
     union all
     select id, value, left(restval, charindex(';', restval)) as val,
            substring(restrval, charindex(';', restval) + 1, len(restval))
     from cte
     where value like '%;%'
    )
select id, val
from cte
union all
select id, value
from t
where value not like '%;%';
```

It is a pain to avoid errors for values that have no semicolons.  I think this is one method for doing this.